# Prevent clicking on dynamically updated array of divs with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm building a tic-tac-toe game, so I have 9 divs with the class "box". When I click on a div, I am pushing the unique ID of that div into an array called "nono". How can I prevent those divs that have an X from being clicked on? I was using .not(), but I read it wouldn't work with a dynamically updating array.

```
var nono = []

$(document).on('click', '.box', function(){
  $(this).html("X");
  var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
  nono.push("#"+currentId);
});
```

Comment: maybe u can just add a `data` attribute to the div that has the **X** and check that `data` attribute when you click the div and add an `event.preventDefault()` or a `return` statement.

Comment: what sushil is saying makes sense. add data-clicked="true" and if thats there return

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<div class="box">Test</div>
<div class="box">Test</div>
<div class="box">Test</div>
<br>
<div class="box">Test</div>
<div class="box">Test</div>
<div class="box">Test</div>
    <br>
<div class="box">Test</div>
<div class="box">Test</div>
        <div class="box">Test</div>

var nono = [];

$(document).on('click', '.box', function(){
    if($(this).html() == "X")
        return;
  $(this).html("X");
  var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
  nono.push("#"+currentId);
  alert("Captured");  
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3xswvwhz/

Comment: You may also use the data-attr as suggested by other but then since you just change the text to 'X' , you technically wouldn't need it here.

Answer (score 1):

Give the clickable boxes a class, e.g. `class="box clickable"`. Delegate your event handler to that class, and remove the class from the element when you add them to the list.

```
var nono = []

$(document).on('click', '.box.clickable', function(){
  $(this).html("X").removeClass("clickable");
  var currentId = $(this).attr('id');
  nono.push("#"+currentId);
});
```